# Ruby on Rails Devise Gem Rememberable Set config.remember_for dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, cookies, devise

I want to set the remember_for duration dynamically for every user. Currently I am setting it like this:

```
config.remember_for = 1.year
```

I know there exists Timeoutable which does what I want but the project is very large and changing Rememberable to Timeoutable causes a lot of errors and will take a lot of time to adapt the whole code.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, why are you replacing Rememberable with Timeoutable? Just add Timeoutable to your model and have both.

Comment: This option is set at a class level so you cannot set it per user.

Comment: @ethanmclark They don't work together. Rememberable overwrites Timeoutable's functionality.